# How do I convert an oracle timestamp value from UTC to EST in a select statement?

Tags: oracle

Hi I have a date field (Open_Time) containing timestamp data.  The times in this column are in UTC. I want to select that column and convert it to EST and insert it into another table.  I want it to be EST for the time at the original timestamp (take into account daylight savings time based on what day month and year it was).  I have been reading about the various timezone functions in oracle but most seem to focus on altering the database's timezone which I don't need to do.  The (Open_Time) field is always recorded in UTC.

BLUF: I need to select a time_stamp field (Open_Time) that was recorded according to UTC time and convert it to what EST was at the time of (Open_Time).  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_Name (
  open_time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);

INSERT INTO Table_Name VALUES ( SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' );
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT open_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utc,
       open_time AT TIME ZONE 'EST' AS est
FROM   Table_Name;
```

**Output**:

```
UTC                                 EST                               
----------------------------------- -----------------------------------
02-MAR-16 22.41.38.344809000 UTC    02-MAR-16 17.41.38.344809000 EST
```

or if you are just using the `TIMESTAMP` data type:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_Name (
  open_time TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO Table_Name VALUES ( SYSTIMESTAMP );
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT CAST( open_time AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utc,
       CAST( open_time AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ) AT TIME ZONE 'EST' AS est
FROM   Table_Name;
```

**Output**:

```
UTC                                 EST                               
----------------------------------- -----------------------------------
02-MAR-16 22.41.38.344809000 UTC    02-MAR-16 17.41.38.344809000 EST
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you so much for taking the time to lay that out so concisely.

Comment: Note timezone `EST` **does not** consider daylight saving time, try `INSERT INTO Table_Name VALUES (SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '6' MONTH) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');` for comparison. Use the region name, e.g. `SELECT open_time AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern'  from ...` or `EST5EDT`

Comment: I am using this, from what I have checked this is doing what I want.  thanks!
`select 
i.dtm_open_time
,FROM_TZ(cast(i.dtm_open_time as timestamp), '0:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern'
from dcc.incident i`